# Weight paint in cycles nodes?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, vertex-groups

I'm trying to use weights from a vertex group in cycles nodes to change the transparency of the mesh. But as far as I know this is still not supported.

Is there any workaround that I could use?

This is what I want to achieve:

[image: weight-painted array]
[image: modifiers stack]

As you can see, I use a *VertexWeightProximity* modifier, to paint the vertex group, and I would like to use it in the node tree to affect the transparency of the mesh. The attribute node doesn't seem to read vertex groups yet.

[image: node tree]

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use Weight Groups?  Vertex Paint works for Cycles Nodes.

Comment: As far as I know, VertexWeightProximity doesn't work with vertex colors, so I couldn't use it.

Comment: I did overlook that little detail.  There is a really old page here about something different but the suggestion that Ideasman42 gives at the end would work for you here I think.  Write a script that transfers the vertex weights to vertex colors.  http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?78119-weight-painting-lt-gt-texture-painting
You could reword your question to ask how this can be done.  There are some very good scripters around here.

Comment: I've been [requesting this feature](http://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-committers/2014-June/043814.html) for so long..

Comment: Sadly, that addon doesn't seem to work with the modifier, as it doesn't read the modified values. But is good to have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This method doesn't use weights, but it seems that your real goal is to get the *proximity* into Cycles. If this is the case then you can get the proximity using a different method called [Dynamic Paint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/dynamic_paint/introduction.html#activating-the-modifier). This will output an image sequence that can be used in Cycles.

Below is a rough example of what dynamic paint can do:

[image]

This will output a vertex colour layer which can be used in cycles like this to produce to the image on the right:

[image]

Miikah, the creator of dynamic paint has a full tutorial here:

http://www.miikahweb.com/en/articles/blender-dynamicpaint-basics

The basic steps on the physics tab is to set the circle segment to be the *brush* like this:

[image]

The circle that will become transparent is set up in the same way as the brush but is set to be the *canvas* with vertex colours set in the output panel:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I knew about the dynamic paint, but I didn't realize it could be useful in this case. I'll use it!

Answer (score 16):

You need to translate vertex weight into some proxy that nodes can read.  Consider using UV as a proxy.  It can be read by nodes and it can easily be mapped to vertex group weight.

Create a new UV mapping for your mesh and set all vertices to 0,0 on that new map.  Add a UV warp modifier editing this new mapping, modulated by the vertex group you want to reference, and set it to use two empties, one located at 1,1 and one at 0,0.  Now, by accessing these new UV coordinates, you're accessing the vertex group modulating the modifier.

Comment: This workaround blown my mind. People, if you seek the dynamic solution here it is

Comment: I can confirm that this hack is insane and saved my life - until the next issue :)

Comment: I'm just guessing that you're another programmer @Nathan. That is a mad-sexy hack.

Comment: Hi Nathan, I really would like to be capable doing this. Unfortunately my knowledge is too low so that i cannot follow your explanation. Could you please explain it with a step by step instruction for noobs?

Comment: @Chris Do your research first-- search, read about using a UV warp modifier-- then, when you have trouble, ask a new, specific question about the part you're getting stuck on.

Comment: Such a cool hack. Seeing the weightmap in object mode helps so much when using other modifiers like 'weight proximity modifier'.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to weight paint is **Vertex Paint**. Vertex paint can be, unlike weight paint, accessed in cycles. After applying your modifier, you can use the information in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15176/3127) to convert your weight paint data to Vertex Colors. Once this is complete, simply use an attribute node:

[image]

Comment: I don't think this will work when the weight is generated dynamically by a modifier.

Comment: @gandalf3 Fixed!

Answer (score 4):

Since Blender 3.0 using weight paint in shaders is pretty easy, you ony need to convert the weight paint with geometry nodes and push the result to the desired/empty vertex paint. After this the vertex color will store the weights and will automatically update. By this method it is even possible to store multiple weights in one vertex color by using the rgb channels

[image]

Comment: What a great solution! And it's so simple. Thank you!