# Export Vertex weights as an image

Tags: mesh, weight-painting, vertex-weights

I have this model I'm trying to export to a posing software, which has its own IK system.

I'm porting this model with a custom outfit, in which I decided the best approach for it would be using "Transfer Weights" from the source model. It worked like expected.

Now, I want to fix the weights according to the IK deformings, and my question is **Is it possible to export the weight paint colors from a mesh?**

My idea is looking at how the mesh deforms with the IK, and if it deforms wrongly, then change the weights of that given segment instead of blindly painting weights on them.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: So is your rig created in blender or the external program?

Comment: It was made on an external program

Answer (score 1):

There is a script that will convert weights to vertex colors.  These can then be baked out to a map.  See [Turn weight paint(vertex groups) into vertex paint?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15172/turn-weight-paintvertex-groups-into-vertex-paint) for script and instructions.

Answer (score 0):

When rigging an object in blender and parenting it to the correct bones using weight painting, these values will be exported when using the FBX export option in blender...

Comment: I'm talking about the weight paint mesh, I mean the weight paint colors baked to an image, like for example, an arm, instead of having the arm texture, it would have the arm texture "tinted" with the weights and that "tint" being exported into a PNG or TGA