# Sticking objects with particles

Tags: particles, eevee-render-engine

How can I stick objects with shapes of my choice (on a model designed by me), on the parts with angles of my choice, very open and very closed through particles?

In short : making dirt on the mesh at its closed and open angle corners with particles making a gradient to the dirt free parts to use with EEVEE ?]

[image]

thank you so much

Comment: You could use the Vertex Paint > Dirty Vertex Colors tool in order to paint where you have concave/convex surfaces, then to convert the vertex paint to vertex group, use an addon, see here https://blog.michelanders.nl/2015/02/transfer-vertex-weights-to-vertex_28.html ... or here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15172/turn-weight-paintvertex-groups-into-vertex-paint