# Can I animate which vertices a certain material is assigned to?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, vertex-groups, vertex-colors

What I want to achieve is to have a low-poly mesh with a certain mesh assigned to a set of vertices, and then be able to animate it to change which vertices are affected. Something like this:

[image: Start Material]

To something like this:

[image: End Material]

I need the solution to work for any shape, and to be able to be animated to at least four different positions, and fairly easily. Any solutions?

Comment: Try animating a mix shader node to change between the light diffuse shader and the darker diffuse shader.

Comment: this [answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15171/5113) may help

Answer (score 3):

Assign different materials with different pass index to the different vertex groups you want to affect.

Enable Pass index on the render layers.

In the Compositor you can then alter the material using the ID mask.

[image]

Comment: This appears to be a shadeless solution, is that the case?

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise indeed!

Comment: Hmm, this is a good answer, but not exactly what I was looking for. I need to keep shading information if at all possible.