# Object Gradual Fade To Transparent

Tags: rendering, animation, texturing, shaders, transparency

Does anyone know how to make an object gradually fade to transparent in a specific direction. An example would be a person walking through and invisible door. So as their foot enters it becomes invisible and then the arm and rest of the body,etc.

Thanks,

Bill

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45866/making-vertical-gradient-then-make-top-half-transparent/45868#45868

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5113/how-to-make-one-object-gradually-disappear-as-it-passes-through-another-object)

Comment: Check out https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111714/add-a-glow-to-a-boolean-modifier-boundary/111715#111715 .  Same thing, but instead of using the boolean target proximity to drive emission add, use it to drive transparency mix.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79851/make-an-objects-visibility-controlled-by-another-object-or-an-empty