# Anyone know how to preview Dynamic Paint weight properly in 2.8?

Tags: dynamic-paint

Does anyone know how to 'see' Dynamic Paint in 'weight' mode in Blender 2.8?
I've trawled this link- https://developer.blender.org/T56349

And this looks like how you're supposed to do it-

*We have workarounds for displaying previews:*

*Vertex Paint:*

- *Configure Output Paintmap Layer and or Wetmap Layer*
- *Switch to Mesh Object Data properties tab*
- *Activate Vertex Color*
- *Switch back to Physics properties tab*
- *Activate workbench vertex color type*

*Weight Paint:*

- *Add material*
- *Configure material to display weights*
- *Switch viewport to Lookdev or rendered mode in EEVEE/Cycles.*

I'm interested in the Weight Paint bit- how do you '*Configure material to display weights*'?
I've tried an attribute node colour & factor outputs, either direct into a principled BSDF, or via a colour ramp, but see nothing after baking the Dynamic paint.

The DP Weight map seems to bake out, and seems to influence smoke sort of correctly, it doesn't do such a good job with particles (used for density), but that could be my setup, or the fact that I can't 'see' the weight map.

Here's a quick test I tried- https://www.dropbox.com/s/54oht3nvnnxljaa/DP_Weight_2.8_Test01.blend?dl=0

Any help- greatly appreciated...

Edit: It does work for particles if you use Monseiur Merle's method of masking out the DP Weight painted part of the canvas (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J313g2N5hZc), then emitting particles from that.
It does not seem to work using the DP Weight map for particle density, like a hand painted weight map will work for particle emission.

Here's a second file showing that- https://www.dropbox.com/s/4cyvqcqgand9ukl/DP_Weight_2.8_Test02.blend?dl=0

Should the DP Weight map work for particle density or do you have to use the mask+weight edit modifier method to get the effect of particles emitting from the weight painted areas only?

Once again, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: On the question: how do you _'Configure material to display weights'_? I believe it's coming up in a future build. In the mean time, there's a deeply cunning solution [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/109099/35559)