# How do I apply an emission modifier to the inside of a cylinder only?

Tags: modifiers, faces, emission

I created arches using an array of cylinders with solidify and bevel modifiers added. I'm using an emission modifier because I want only the inside of the arches to glow -- but when I apply the modifier, the entire cylinder glows instead. I tried selecting only the faces inside the cylinder, but even then the modifier applies itself to the entire thing.

Comment: If you mean 'Emission Material', The _Solidify_ modifier has a 'Material Offset' setting .. see [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/189578/35559)

Comment: Ah this helped quite a bit! Now the only issue is that the emission modifier has been applied to the outside of the cylinder rather than the inside...any ideas on how to inverse this? I tried playing with the offset and thickness in the solidify modifier and so far nothing.

Comment: Select the first material, then click the little globe next to its name (right above the assign button) and pick the other material from the list of available materials that appears (all the ones you've made). Do the same for the second (inversely). In essence - swap the materials in their slots (material offset is based on slot order - not the material within it).