# need help making wave breaking look real with ocean modifier - using vertex weight or pointiness maybe?

Tags: vertex-weights, ocean-simulation

I am using the ocean modifier along with some interesting arrangement of modifiers to make it look like its breaking on a beach.

[image: current render]

I'm actually quite pleased with the way it looks..but I want to try to add that last bit of realism by attempting to emulate some foam.

I would be happy with just being able to colour the tips a bit white, or if there is a way to generate this foam that'd be great - I'm not that familiar with the ocean modifier. I know there's a way to get foam but don't know how to use it properly.

I tried using a geometry node and separate xyz node to use z in a colorramp, but it doesn't look good.

I tried using the pointiness from the geometry node but it didn't actually do anything? I tried applying my modifiers first too to see if that was why, but didn't seem to give me anything.

I also have vertex weighting for vertices close to shore as part of the modifiers I used to shape the waves at the beach:

[image: vertex weight]

Ideally I would be able to use this as an input for a shading node?

Any ideas on how I could make these waves look a bit more real?

Would appreciate it. Using 2.83.

UPDATE

I was able to find a hack to modulate the UV map using the vertex weight so I can access it from a shader node, using this trick:

[link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15167/weight-paint-in-cycles-nodes?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

(Nathan's answer)

The current look, and shader node set up:

[image]

obviously it's a start, but the white/foam is not really on the crest of the waves.

Please any suggestions!! I would really appreciate it