# Assigning materials to faces independently in 2 objects with the same mesh data

Tags: mesh, materials, faces

I have two objects, A and B, with the same mesh data. I am assigning material M to some faces of A. What I want is to independently be able to assign different material to different set of faces in object B.

All my objects' materials are linked to "Object".
What I observe, independence is only available when using single material per entire object and not when assigning materials to faces. When I do the latter, each object sharing the same mesh data (A and B in my example) shares face selection for each material so there is a link between objects I do not want to have.

```
Simple example:

Objects: A, B (each has mesh data D)
D mesh data is consisted of faces: F1 F2 F3 F4
Objectives:
- Object A has material M1 assigned to F1 and F2
- Object B has material M2 assigned to F2 and F3
- No other faces have material assigned
```

PS: I do not want to duplicate mesh data of A and B (of course for project's sanity reasons).

Blender 2.91.0

Comment: Hello :). Well, material slots are a part of mesh data. To assign materials to different faces, you need to use some other way than material slots (vertex groups/UV maps,...)

Comment: Thanks @JachymMichal, do you mean vertex groups+UV maps? Because vertex groups alone let me to only select faces that I can traditionally assign material to them, what is the original challenge I am describing.

Comment: Hey :). I just realized this isn't as easy as I thought - but these answers could help: [Weight paint in cycles nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15167/78972)