# How to see Vertex weights on a mesh in Edit mode?

Tags: edit-mode, vertex-weights

This thing is new to me because I didn't saw or noticed it (if it already exist on the older versions of Blender)( I'm using 3.01 ). If you go into Edit mode, select the Items tab, it will show you the Vertex Weights of a mesh.

In this mesh, you can see the Weights it has on the **Items tab**
[image: In this mesh, you can see the Weights it has on the Items tab]

In this one, it's doesn't show it
[image: In this one, it's doesn't show it]

Comment: Just a side note: In the "Overlays" menu there is an option "Shading > Vertex Group Weights". When this option is activated, the weights are displayed as colors, just like in the "Weight Paint" mode.

Answer (score 2):

In the Numbers Panel you only see a weight of a single vertex - you need to have a vertex active (marked white). Since it's possible to select multiple vertices without making one active, it's also possible to not see a weight for any vertex.

If you want to see weights for multiple vertices, you could use this answer:

[how can i use vertex weight value in shader nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/253061/60486)

And in order to set weight for all selected vertices, you can do so in *Object Data Properties* [image]

Of course there's also *Weight Paint Mode*.

Comment: Selecting a vertex worked, Thank you very much!