# Use animated vertex weights in shader editor

Tags: materials, vertex-groups

I want to recreate the effect shown in this video and picture below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tUql7f7iECE.

[image]

I found this post on how to use vertex weights in the shader editor:
[how can i use vertex weight value in shader nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/228621/how-can-i-use-vertex-weight-value-in-shader-nodes)

But I cannot figure out how to use the vertex group (which is **animated** using the VertexWeightProximity Modifier) in the shader editor, to get two materials on the mesh.

What I did so far:

- Created Geonodes on my mesh, capture the vertex group and created an output.

[image]

- I then used the attribute in the shader editor in combination with a colorramp. But it seems that the captured vertex group in geonodes is still just my initial vertex group, unaffected by the VertexWeightProximity Modifier.

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I use the animated vertex group in the shader editor to get the two materials working?

Comment: File would help.  Capturing is unnecessary, and capturing as boolean/face is probably not what you want-- you want float/point, probably.  Attribute output type also matters.  Modifier order also matters (you need the vertex weight prox before the GN modifier.)  Shader usage could potentially matter as well, although it's less likely you did something wrong there.

Comment: Ok, so I don't know where I made a mistake, but I went through the workflow for the 50th time and now it works. I think capturing "float/point" could the the problem: https://we.tl/t-PKWr56rtgX