# How to use vertex weight to control gravity strength in particle system?

Tags: particles, vertex-weights

I want to use preset vertex weights to control the strength of gravity in the particle system, but I found that the gravity option only supports textures.

So is there a way to convert the vertex weights I set into textures or something. My vertex weight is a animated weight, generated by the Vertex Weight Proximity Modifier, and the result will be that the upper position is always affected by less gravity (the circle is constantly rotating).

[image]

Comment: Would geometry nodes solution ok for u?

Comment: Yes. Please!! Thanks~

Comment: can you link a video how the end effect should look like please? because i am still not sure how it should look like...

Comment: meanwhile you could read this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15167/weight-paint-in-cycles-nodes/109099#109099 ...this might help you

Comment: I'm sorry for my expressiveness. The torus I posted works as a particle emitter, and I want the emitted particles to be given the corresponding gravitational strength using vertex weights in picture.(The way the ring rotates is like a ferris wheel thing)

Answer (score 0):

ok, here a solution with particles:

I have a torus with a force like this:

[image]

so the force will be driven by the surface.

I added a vertex group to the torus with all vertices.

And i added the vertexweightproximity to the torus with the sphere as "reactor", which i animate in a circle along the torus, and with a mask modifier i delete parts of the torus and the force modifier at last.

Result looks like this:

[image]

Note: i turned gravity completely off for this so the particles are only influenced by the force.